# Sliding-In UIView From Bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am trying to build a custom-looking action sheet. I thought the easiest way would be creating a view as a subview and assign constraint of subview's top to superview's bottom. And at the same time assigning a cover view with some opacity. Thus, I could have different versions of subview and I can initialise the necessary one and slide it.

[image]  [image]

I couldn't find anything useful for Swift, so, using [this obj-c answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484328/4705339), I tried to convert it to Swift. I achieved the opaque background with this however translating constraints doesn't seem to work.

```
 var coverView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.4)
    coverView.alpha = 1.0
    self.view.addSubview(coverView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(coverView)
} 

//doesn't work
 self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[coverView]|", options: kNilOptions, metrics: nil, views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(coverView)))
 self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[coverView]|", options: kNilOptions, metrics: nil, views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(coverView)))
```

I got confused on instantiating the view and applying transition animation. If I choose to create a UIView under ViewController, I cannot adjust constraints to adjust `equal width` of subview to superview.

[image]

How can I use the UIView that I created as a Subview (in Storyboard) and then adjust its width constraints so the UI doesn't bug? Also, how can I apply the transition animation so it seems natural?

[This link should be here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514836/how-to-add-bottom-swipe-up-view-ios/32516167#32516167)

Comment: I wrote something like this a few years ago. https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBMenuController

Comment: @EICaptain Your example makes sense however, I don't want it to be shown on my super-UIView, instead I want it to formed under the superview (under the bottom) and then slide it.. How can I use the constraints? Should I try to get the height of the superview and then place the origin y for the UIView? I'd be grateful for hearing an answer from you if you have time

Comment: @Moshe your one is an actioncontroller, isn't it? I won't to have a custom view instead

Comment: If you are adding constraints, make sure you set `translatesAutoSizingMaskIntoConstraints=false` in your coverView

Comment: @senty - mine is a UIView subclass. It's pre-autolayout but it should work with autolayout.

Comment: @moshe I'm trying to understand the code but obj-c just doesn't make sense to me.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested you use UIView xib file and design your view then load in your view controller.

Ex:

**Step 1:**

Create xib for view
[image]

**Step 2:**
Set background color black for this view, opacity 62% and Alpha = 1
[image]

**Step 3:**
Take new simple UIView and Design your actual view and set constraint.

For **Exp:**
[image]

In your case set view in bottom.
**Step 4:**
Load xib in view controller.

```
class calendarViewController: UIViewController
{
    var popUpView: popUpView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       bookingConfirmView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("popUpView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! popUpView
    // Set Delegate for xib textField
    self.popUpView.Name.delegate = self
    self.popUpView.MobileNo.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**

Add this line to where you want to populate view.

```
self.view.addSubview(bookingConfirmView)
self.bookingConfirmView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

Comment: Okay. Can you please add an example how to add UIView xib inside the my main UIView, and adjust constraints, so my subview gets created below the bottom of the superview with constraints added?

Comment: Now you can see the exp.